# How to rename the browser tab for customer login page magento2

Tags: magento2.3, customer, customer-account, customer-login

I am using magento 2.3.
I want the browser tab to say something like: 'seller login instead of customer login'.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Title can be set from layout file, Create:

> app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml

with following content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Seller Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
           <action method="setPageTitle">
              <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Some Page Title </argument>
           </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

**NOTE** : If You want same browser tab and page title, You can skip `body` code from file.

Comment: Thank You so much

Comment: welcome @gill :)